# Google GMail API `installed` app shows IOError 13 from module SSL.py w/o sudo

Tags: python, ssl, privileges, gmail-api

I am playing around with GMAIL API to create an app to send auto emails from my server. Running my application as a simple user has the following results:

```
pankgeorg@snf-25181:~/tomotech/gmailer$ python mailer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailer.py", line 36, in <module>
    gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_api_python_client-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 198, in build
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 547, in new_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1593, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1335, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1257, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1021, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 886, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 496, in __init__
    self._context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

On the other hand, running with sudo works perfectly

```
pankgeorg@snf-25181:~/tomotech/gmailer$ sudo python mailer.py
Message Id: 14ad0aea05e*****
```

To be completely honest, in order to authenicate using `--noauth_local_webserver`, I run the command with sudo, authenticated and `chown` the `gmail.storage` to myself again.
Also, I installed using `easy_install` because `pip install` was giving me the following error:

```
pankgeorg@snf-25181:~/tomotech/gmailer$ sudo pip install --upgrade google_api_python_client
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1096, in prepare_files
    req_to_install, self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 670, in get_page
    resp = session.get(url, headers={"Accept": "text/html"})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 395, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 506, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 168, in resolve_redirects
    allow_redirects=False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 480, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 285, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1001, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1035, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 997, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 850, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 826, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 323, in sendall
    return self.connection.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 969, in sendall
    raise TypeError("buf must be a byte string")
TypeError: buf must be a byte string

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.logrom oath2client import tool
```

It is my understanding that the root of the problem is the same in both cases.
I also have to note that my laptop (on which I can authenticate normally, on webbrowser, instead of --noauth_local_webserver) it works just fine, even though the installation is done the same way (the problem with pip appears there too).

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post!
Tutorials I used: 
[parse arg](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#commandline) 
[code for sending mails](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) 
application body is pretty much the quickstart for gmail api.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The httplib2 installer sets incorrect permissions for its `httplib2/cacerts.txt` file.  One solution is to simply make its files readable by anyone by running

```
chmod o+r -R  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg
```

However, it may be better to uninstall the version installed by pip, and use your operating system's package manager instead, which probably has the correct permissions for all files.  On Debian, this could be accomplished with

```
pip uninstall httplib2
apt-get install python-httplib2
```

Comment: Not sure why someone gave this -1.. Solved the problem for me on OSX:
sudo chmod o+r /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/httplib2/cacerts.txt

Comment: sudo chmod o+r /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/h‌​ttplib2/cacerts.txt worked in osx 10.11.6

Comment: In my case I had two version installed, I don't know why. `pip uninstall httplib2` removed the old version (which had just been installed) and all went back to normal. Make sure you read which version `pip` is removing or things could end badly.